# How to install old versions of Firefox on newer versions of Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I am on Ubuntu 11.10 (which comes with FF8), and I am going to have to test an app that only supports FF3.5. I vaguely remember a page with old versions of the browser, and links to versions for each OS, but for the life of me, I can't find anything other then Windows installers on the Mozilla site / FTP. There is a related question here on superuser where someone links to oldapps.com, but even there it is pure Windows installers.

anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest download tar version of old Firefox (FF3.5). https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all-older.html -- 3.6.24 version. untar it and export the path of firefox binary or use it from that location.

Ok found this ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/ have everything listed there :)

Comment: so thats better then I could find, but do you know if there is anything like it for 3.5? like a full listing of the 3.6 branch would be amazing...

Comment: Yes even I searched for it couldn't find I'll get back to you if I find it :)

Comment: @MattBriggs: Just updated answer with listing for all versions of FF :)